# How to shift a square into the direction of a given angle so that the old and new borders overlap

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently I had a problem where I had to shift a square called `r` into a specific direction, e.g. $45$°.

This is what you have:

- The center of `r`
- The side length of `r`
- Resulting out of this you can calculate the edge points of `r`
- A given direction angle `a`

The challenge is to shift `r` so that one side of `r` and the shifted square match (for specific angles they have one equal edge point, e.g. for $45$°).

**Examples:**

1. Original `r` (which is blue) shifted in the direction of `a=315°`:

[image]

2. Original `r` (which is blue) shifted in the direction of `a=111°`:

[image]

Here is my approach (and I hope for easier solutions):

- Setup a linear equation using given angle `a` and the center point
- Calculate the intersection between this linear equation and the appropriate side of `r`. E.g. $111$° would result in an intersection with the top line of `r`. Thus $y$ of the intersection point can be directly taken from the top left or top right edge point. $x$ can be calculated whereas $m$ equals $0$° since the top line is a horizontal line.
- When having the center and intersection point I can use Pythagoras' theorem to calculate the length `l` between those points.
- Having `l` allows me to calculate the new center point by using the calculated intersection point, the given angle `a` and `l`

Main drawbacks of my approach:

1. It's complicated
2. I have to make special considerations for each interval $[45,135],[135,225][225,315]$, $[0, 45]$ & $[315,359]$ to identify the intersection point.

So I would like to discuss this problem here in the hope of a much nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

The $x$ and $y$ shifts are $d\cos(\theta)$ and $d\sin(\theta)$ respectively, for some $d$, and the largest of them must equal $r$ (in absolute value).

Hence,

$$d=r\max\left(\frac1{|\cos(\theta)|}, \frac1{|\sin(\theta)|}\right).$$

One of the shifts is $\pm r$, and the other is $\pm r\min(|\tan(\theta)|,|\cot(\theta)|)$.

Comment: Could you explain your solution a bit more? d is the diagonal? How exactly are the new coordinates calculated using your approach? One special case is 0° since `1/abs(sin(0))` is not defined.